# Request Uri - How much of the string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth

Would I include this whole thing (isn't that a Url not a Uri if I include the entire string here) for a Uri?

http://someThirdPartyApi.com/api/v1/cases.json

or would it just be this portion for the Uri when making OAuth requests?

/api/v1/cases.json

UPDATED - (context):

So for example with OAuth, as you know, part of the signature is the Base Uri.  I don't understand if that means this entire address or just /api/v1/cases.json which I guess would be the resource part of the Url?  I don't get it.  What should I be passing as part of the signature creation for the Uri part?

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. Can you show a bit of code that shows the context of your question?

Comment: A Url is a Uri (ie. Urls are just one type of Uri).

Comment: It's pretty clear what I'm asking here.  Any API asks for a Uri to be sent to request a resource (resource of the API, i.e. data such as a customer) you're trying to get at.  I just don't know what part is the "Uri"...all of it or just the part after the domain?  I've seen some reference it as the whole Url and some say show only the part after the domain (i.e. again in my example after the domain would be the /api/v1/cases.json part)

Comment: So patmortech, in the case of OAuth, when you create the signature, it says to only use the Uri...so is that all of it above or only the part that starts at /api... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `http://someThirdPartyApi.com/api/v1/cases.json` is an absolute URL, while `/api/v1/cases.json` is a relative URL.

You can use relative URL when you're in a document located at some URL and you want to reference some other “close” URL (for example on the same domain name). So, for example, in the document located at `http://someThirdPartyApi.com/index.aspx`, both of your URLs should be treated the same.

If you're not in a document located at the same domain, you should use the absolute URL.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was asking fore.  It gets confusing when you're working with stuff like OAuth.